# How to combine FCNN and RNN in Tensorflow?

Tags: scope, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I want to make a Neural Network, which would have recurrency (for example, LSTM) at some layers and normal connections (FC) at others.
I cannot find a way to do it in Tensorflow.
It works, if I have only FC layers, but I don't see how to add just one recurrent layer properly.

I create a network in a following way :

```
with tf.variable_scope("autoencoder_variables", reuse=None) as scope:

  for i in xrange(self.__num_hidden_layers + 1):
    # Train weights
    name_w = self._weights_str.format(i + 1)
    w_shape = (self.__shape[i], self.__shape[i + 1])
    a = tf.multiply(4.0, tf.sqrt(6.0 / (w_shape[0] + w_shape[1])))
    w_init = tf.random_uniform(w_shape, -1 * a, a)
    self[name_w] = tf.Variable(w_init,
                               name=name_w,
                               trainable=True)
    # Train biases
    name_b = self._biases_str.format(i + 1)
    b_shape = (self.__shape[i + 1],)
    b_init = tf.zeros(b_shape)
    self[name_b] = tf.Variable(b_init, trainable=True, name=name_b)

    if i+1 == self.__recurrent_layer:
      # Create an LSTM cell
      lstm_size = self.__shape[self.__recurrent_layer]
      self['lstm'] = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
```

It should process the batches in a sequential order. I have a function for processing just one time-step, which will be called later, by a function, which process the whole sequence :

```
def single_run(self, input_pl, state, just_middle = False):
  """Get the output of the autoencoder for a single batch

  Args:
    input_pl:     tf placeholder for ae input data of size [batch_size, DoF]
    state:        current state of LSTM memory units
    just_middle : will indicate if we want to extract only the middle layer of the network
  Returns:
    Tensor of output
  """

  last_output = input_pl

  # Pass through the network
  for i in xrange(self.num_hidden_layers+1):

    if(i!=self.__recurrent_layer):
      w = self._w(i + 1)
      b = self._b(i + 1)
      last_output = self._activate(last_output, w, b)

    else:
      last_output, state = self['lstm'](last_output,state)

  return last_output
```

The following function should take sequence of batches as input and produce sequence of batches as an output:

```
def process_sequences(self, input_seq_pl, dropout, just_middle = False):
  """Get the output of the autoencoder

  Args:
    input_seq_pl:     input data of size [batch_size, sequence_length, DoF]
    dropout:          dropout rate
    just_middle :     indicate if we want to extract only the middle layer of the network
  Returns:
    Tensor of output
  """

  if(~just_middle): # if not middle layer
    numb_layers = self.__num_hidden_layers+1
  else:
    numb_layers = FLAGS.middle_layer

  with tf.variable_scope("process_sequence", reuse=None) as scope:

    # Initial state of the LSTM memory.
    state = initial_state = self['lstm'].zero_state(FLAGS.batch_size, tf.float32)

    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() # THIS IS IMPORTANT LINE

    # First - Apply Dropout
    the_whole_sequences = tf.nn.dropout(input_seq_pl, dropout)

    # Take batches for every time step and run them through the network
    # Stack all their outputs
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.convert_to_tensor(state, name='state') ]): # do not let paralelize the loop
      stacked_outputs = tf.stack( [ self.single_run(the_whole_sequences[:,time_st,:], state, just_middle) for time_st in range(self.sequence_length) ])

    # Transpose output from the shape [sequence_length, batch_size, DoF] into [batch_size, sequence_length, DoF]

    output = tf.transpose(stacked_outputs , perm=[1, 0, 2])

  return output
```

The issue is with a variable scopes and their property "reuse".

If I run this code as it is I am getting the following error:
' Variable Train/process_sequence/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope? '

If I comment out the line, which tell it to reuse variables ( tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables() ) I am getting the following error:
'Variable Train/process_sequence/basic_lstm_cell/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?'

It seems, that we need "reuse=None" for the weights of the LSTM cell to be initialized and we need "reuse=True" in order to call the LSTM cell.

Please, help me to figure out the way to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have solved this issue using the hack from the official Tensorflow RNN example (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent) with the following code

```
with tf.variable_scope("RNN"):
  for time_step in range(num_steps):
    if time_step > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    (cell_output, state) = cell(inputs[:, time_step, :], state)
    outputs.append(cell_output)
```

The hack is that when we run LSTM first time, tf.get_variable_scope().reuse is set to False, so that the new LSTM cell is created. When we run it next time, we set tf.get_variable_scope().reuse to True, so that we are using the LSTM,  which was already created.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're creating variables with tf.Variable. Please, use tf.get_variable instead -- does this solve your issue?

Comment: The problem arise for LSTM cell. How can I use tf.get_variable while creating LSTM cell ? ( now I do the following : self['lstm'] = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size) )